# Trc-20 transaction listening

Tags: fetch-api, tron

I have a huge list of addresses that I need to watch for incoming trc-20 token transfers, and if there's a transaction containing one of my address, add it's information to database.

As is see, there's no possible way to watch transactions with websockets, so i need to use http requests.

```
    const trc20ContractAddress = "TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t";

    let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(trc20ContractAddress);
        
    let result = await tronGrid.contract.getEvents(trc20ContractAddress, {
                only_confirmed: false,
                event_name: "Transfer",
                limit: 200,
                min_timestamp: timestamp,
                order_by: "timestamp,asc"
            })
    console.log(result)
```

Tron network can handle 2000 transactions per second, the maximum limit per request is 200, so what's the optimal algorithm for watching them? Considering that each request has a delay, and i can't watch the entire block.

Answer (score 0):

There is some limitation not using your own Fullnode. If you are looking for best solution deploy your own Fullnode and follow event subscription:
[event-subscription](https://developers.tron.network/docs/event-subscription)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What I did was get new blocks every 5-6 seconds.

And have 3-4 more crons that runs every second to get transactions from the blocks. You have to write the code to ensure those crons arent processing the same/processed block and also prevent race condition (I suggest using redis SETNX).

And once the block processing is completed you should have all your transactions that you need.

Please note that getting transactions from Tronscan by block isn’t accurate 100% for the confirmation status. I suggest you to save the unconfirmed transactions in ur db somewhere and have another cron(s) to fetch the detail.